# How to close a Full Screen menu when clicked on any of the links inside the menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, less

I want to implement https://codepen.io/brenden/pen/VLjKMQ/ this menu in my project/website but I can't get the menu to close after I click any link or even navigate it to my desired section(of my one-page website).

```
<h1>Your Content</h1>
<div class="outer-menu">
  <input class="checkbox-toggle" type="checkbox" />
  <div class="hamburger">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: im sorry if i messed up the format of asking question here this is my first question

Comment: You need to add logic that captures the click of the links and toggles the checkbox-toggle to checked = false.  Otherwise, put a label around your links and have them have a for="idOfTheCheckbox" and it will do it without any added javascript

Comment: @Taplar thanks im gonna try it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// bind a click listener to the entire menu
document.querySelector('.menu').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  // check to see if the element clicked was a link
  if (e.target.tagName === 'A') {
    // set the checkbox to checked false
    document.querySelector('.checkbox-toggle').checked = false;
  }
});
```